# Pass array of latitude and longitude to CLLocationCoordinate2DMake in swift

Tags: mapkit, swift4

i have two arrays one consists latitude in it and second one has longitude. I'm trying to pass it to the CLLocationCoordinate2DMake. From response i'm getting latitude and longitude but they are in string format. i'm converting it to Double. but when i pass that array it shows me an error `Cannot convert value of type '[Double]' to expected argument type 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'Double')`

I have tried this code,

```
    var latitudeArray = [Double]()
var longitudeArray = [Double]()
latitudeArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "latitudeArray") as! [Double]
    longitudeArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "longitudeArray") as! [Double]

    print(latitudeArray)
    print(longitudeArray)
  let location = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitudeArray, longitudeArray)
    mapView.setRegion(MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 1500, 1500), animated: true)

    let pin = MapPin.init(title: name!, locationName: name!, coordinate: location)
    mapView.addAnnotation(pin).
```

How can i pass my array to it? I want the map to show all the location with lat and lng i'm passing to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few flaws. First of all, CLLocationCoordinate2DMake takes a single `Double` for each parameter, while you're trying to use an `Array` of `Double`s. Your code is kinda unclear on wether you actually want to show the pins on your map in addition to fitting all the coordinates you have stored to `UserDefaults`, so the following code does both.

The following code will

- Take an array of latitudes and an array of longitudes
- Turn them into coordinate objects
- Turn those coordinates into map annotations
- Add those annotations to the map
- Zoom the map to fit all of the annotations

Here you go!

```
    let latitudes = [Double]()
    let longitudes = [Double]()
    let names = [String]()

    let coordinates = zip(latitudes, longitudes).map(CLLocationCoordinate2D.init)

    let annotations = zip(coordinates, names)
        .map { (coordinate, name) -> MKPointAnnotation in
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

            annotation.coordinate = coordinate
            annotation.title = name

            return annotation
        }

    map.addAnnotations(annotations)
    map.showAnnotations(annotations, animated: true)
```

From `showAnnotations` docs:

> Sets the visible region so that the map displays the specified annotations.

Comment: can u please explain this. @Oscar Apeland

Comment: @Hamza Added some more explanations :)

Comment: i just have to show the location with mappin. @Oscar Apeland

Comment: Then the code I wrote for you does what you want :)

Comment: how can i pass my array that having name for the location? @Oscar Apeland

Comment: Thanks a lot i got that. @Oscar Apeland